# iPhone 11: No data from microphone after attaching a mixer to AVAudioEngine

Tags: swift, iphone, audio-recording

I have a recording app that uses AVAudioEngine. I am connecting a mixer to microphone to convert the data to desired format, then attach a tap to the mixer to retrieve the data. It used to work just fine until iPhone 11 was released. In iPhone 11 the data I get from microphone is simply complete silence.

After getting problem reported from users of the app I first checked the iPhone 11 simulator in newest XCode and, strange enough, it is working fine there. So I bought myself shiny new iPhone 11 and I could only confirm the app records nothing but silence.

The problematic part is this:

```
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
let main = audioEngine.mainMixerNode
let inputFormat = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true)

audioEngine.attach(downMixer)
audioEngine.connect(inputNode, to: downMixer, format: inputFormat)
audioEngine.connect(downMixer, to: main, format: outputFormat)
downMixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 640, format: outputFormat) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
    print("First 20 bytes of recorded data:", terminator: " ")
    let data = Data(buffer: buffer)
    var i = 0
    for byte in data {
        print("\(byte)", terminator: ", ")
        i += 1
        if i > 20 {
            break;
        }
    }
    print("")
}
```

Once these lines:

```
audioEngine.connect(inputNode, to: downMixer, format: inputFormat)
audioEngine.connect(downMixer, to: main, format: outputFormat)
```

get executed, the output from the mic becomes null:

```
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
First 20 bytes of recorded data: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
etc.
```

I did a search on the internet and it seems no one is having similar problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @RajAggrawal if you don't put downsampling mixer and read directly from mic input all works as it should, so my solution was to recode my app and do resampling manually. Actually I opened tech support incident with Apple, and the reply was "I am able to reproduce the behavior on an iPhone 11, and it doesn’t seem to be related to the order in which the nodes are configured. I’ve asked engineering for opinions on this behavior, but I don’t have an answer yet." It was almost a month ago and then nothing. It seems almost no one is using audio engine this way...